# Autoscroll when dragging react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, drag-and-drop, overflow

I have a nested list Items which can be dragged and dropped. However, when I reach to the bottom of the page , I wish it to automatically scrolled down. For example :

[image]

As you can see from that image that there are more items down there but it just refused to scroll down.

Attached is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "../list3.css";

const List5 = () => {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([
    {
      value: "62bac6eddfe90a7c09873d92",
      title: "A",
      parent: null,
      level: 1,
      children: [
        {
          value: "62bac35ba30786989841809b",
          title: "B",
          parent: "62bac6eddfe90a7c09873d92",
          level: 2,
          children: [
            {
              value: "62bac5af6b6581786cb192e4",
              title: "C",
              parent: "62bac35ba30786989841809b",
              level: 3,
              children: [
                {
                  value: "62bac5af6b6581786cb1999g",
                  title: "F",
                  parent: "62bac5af6b6581786cb192e4",
                  level: 4,
                  children: [
                    {
                      value: "62bac5af6b6581786cc2000h",
                      title: "G",
                      parent: "62bac5af6b6581786cb1999g",
                      level: 5,
                    },
                    {
                      value: "62bac5af6b6581786cc2777j",
                      title: "I",
                      parent: "62bac5af6b6581786cb1999g",
                      level: 5,
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              value: "62bac6696b6581786cb192e7",
              title: "D",
              parent: "62bac35ba30786989841809b",
              level: 3,
              children: [
                {
                  value: "62bac6696b6581786c2003A",
                  title: "H",
                  parent: "62bac6696b6581786cb192e7",
                  level: 4,
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          value: "62bac6696b6581786cb1945P",
          title: "E",
          parent: "62bac6eddfe90a7c09873d92",
          level: 2,
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);
  const sortList = useRef(null);
  const currentItem = useRef(null);
  const targetItem = useRef(null);
  const isSwap = useRef(false); //to handle swapping of nodes only if they are siblings


  const handleDragStart = (e) => {
    currentItem.current = e.target;
    currentItem.current.classList.add("current");
    if (sortList.current) {
      const sortListElem = sortList.current;
      let items = sortListElem.getElementsByTagName("li");
      for (const item of items) {
        if (item !== currentItem.current) {
          item.classList.add("hint");
        }
      }
    }
  };

  const handleDragEnter = (e) => {
    targetItem.current = e.target;
    if (targetItem.current.tagName === "LI") {
      targetItem.current.classList.add("targetLi");
    }
    if (targetItem.current.className === "droppable") {
      targetItem.current.classList.add("activeChild");
    }
  };

  const handleDragLeave = (e) => {
    if (e.target !== targetItem.current) {
      e.target.classList.remove("activeChild");
      e.target.classList.remove("targetLi");
    }
  };

  // DRAG END - REMOVE ALL HIGHLIGHTS
  const handleDragEnd = (e) => {
    const sortListElem = sortList.current;
    let items = sortListElem.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (const it of items) {
      it.classList.remove("hint");
      it.classList.remove("active");
    }
    currentItem.current.classList.remove("current");
    targetItem.current.classList.remove("activeChild");
    targetItem.current.classList.remove("targetLi");
  };

  const handleDragOver = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  const handleDrop = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!targetItem.current.getAttribute("nodeid")) {
      return;
    }

  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("dragstart", handleDragStart);
    document.addEventListener("dragenter", handleDragEnter);
    document.addEventListener("dragleave", handleDragLeave);
    document.addEventListener("dragend", handleDragEnd);
    document.addEventListener("dragover", handleDragOver);
    document.addEventListener("dragover", handleDragOver);
    document.addEventListener("drop", handleDrop);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("dragstart", handleDragStart);
      document.removeEventListener("dragenter", handleDragEnter);
      document.removeEventListener("dragleave", handleDragLeave);
      document.removeEventListener("dragend", handleDragEnd);
      document.removeEventListener("dragover", handleDragOver);
      document.addEventListener("drop", handleDrop);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <ul id="sortList" className="slist" ref={sortList}>
        <ListItems categories={categories}></ListItems>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

function ListItems({ categories }) {
  if (!categories) {
    return <h2>Loading...</h2>;
  }
  return (
    <div className="nested-div">
      {categories &&
        categories.map((category, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index} className="nested-item">
              <li
                nodeid={category.value}
                draggable={category.parent ? true : false}
              >
                {" "}
                {category.title}
              </li>
              <div className="droppable" nodeid={category.value}></div>
              {category.children && (
                <ListItems categories={category.children} />
              )}
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default List5;
```

What I have tried is by adding css property of overflow css property to the main div. Attched is my css

```
/* (A) LIST STYLES */
.slist {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.slist li {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

/* (B) DRAG-AND-DROP HINT */
.slist li.hint {
  border: 1px solid #ffc49a;
  background: #feffb4;
}
.slist li.active {
  border: 1px solid #ffa5a5;
  background: #ffe7e7;
}
.slist li.targetLi {
  background-color: red;
}
.nested-div {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.nested-item {
  margin-left: 2em;
}

.slist li.current {
  border: 5px solid aqua;
}

.droppable {
  padding: 5px;
}

.droppable.activeChild {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.container {
  overflow: scroll;
}

#sortList {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Really appreciate all the help given.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

try this for bottom scrolling when object is dragged:

- find the y-axis value of the object you are dragging
- get the window bottom y-axis (you will probably need to calculate this by getting the window's topY + the window's height)
- check if the object's y-axis different by 200 (can be changed to when you want the scroll to start) from the window's bottom Y-axis and scroll the window/parent-element by number of pixels you choose. (this will probably be in the useEffect of the dragging element, when its dragged check if element reached the point at the bottom you set, and if so, scroll)

This is scrolling only for the bottom, which is probably the harder part. you will have to do something similar for it to scroll up.